# How do I extract the index or name of the list item within FUN of lapply?

Tags: r, list, lapply

Say I have a list of lists `lists`:

```
> lists
$a
[1] "fas"    "asdfas"    "adfaff" ...

$b
[1] "jnfg"   "gfsdgs"    "fdsafa" ...

...
```

I'd like to export each list into its own csv file with the filename being the list index. I'm trying to do it using `lapply` instead of a for loop, is that possible? The difficulty for me is how do I extract the list index (or name in this case) out inside of the `FUN`? For example, if I were to name them randomly I can do this:

```
lapply(lists, function (x)
       write.table(paste(sample(1:100000000,1), ".csv", sep=""),
                   sep=",", col.names=F, row.names=F))
```

---

**Edit:** Sample `dput`: http://pastebin.com/a0eEkT1z

**Edit2:** Shorter sample: (← this one is more sensible)

```
list(c("Itm2a", "Rplp2", "Arl6ip5", "Crygn", "Znrf1", "Gm5766", 
"D19Ertd652e", "Nkap"), c("Sergef", "2610002I17Rik", "Hjurp", 
"Mns1", "Top3a", "Ldlrap1", "Ube2c", "Cnot3", "Irf6"), c("Fam109a", 
"Rps3a", "Dut", "Atm", "Fancg", "S100a5", "Lpcat2", "Sec23ip"
))
```

Comment: Provide an example of 'lists' using `dput` please.

Comment: You cannot. They're not there. The names are "kept to the side" and only reapplied after the resutls are returned. Using `lapply` or `sapply` on `names(df)` is one metthoid,. You could also use `mapply` with names(df) as one of the arguments.

Comment: If you had the choice between providing an example which was 5 lines long, or an example that is 2000 lines, which would you say is more sensible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. One trick is to use `lapply` to loop over the names or you can use `Map` to do something like

```
Map(function (name, data)
       write.table(data, paste0(name, ".csv"),
                   sep=",", col.names=F, row.names=F)
, names(lists), lists)
```

Comment: you can also do: `Map(write.table, x=lists, file=paste0(names(lists),".csv"), sep=",", col.names=F, row.names=F)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mapply`

```
mapply(function(name, x) {
    write.table(x, paste0(name, ".csv"), sep=",", col.names=F, row.names=F)
}, names(lists), lists)
```

Or actually using `lapply` is also possible

```
lapply(names(lists), function(name) {
    write.table(lists[name], paste0(name, ".csv"), sep=",", col.names=F, row.names=F)
})
```